# Determine the third point in right triangle only knowing the coordinates of the other two points

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

I have a right triangle $ABC$. I am given the coordinates of the two points $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $C(x_2, y_2)$. Given points $A$ and $C$, I want to determine the coordinates of $B$.  I know there are two solutions for this. I want to find them both.

[image: This image]

Comment: Are the legs supposed to be parallel to the axes, as the picture kind of suggests?

Comment: No, not always .

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Then there are infinitely many such triangles.

Comment: I think you guys, got me wrong, what I meant that A and C are two constant points they may be for example $A(4,3)$ a,d $C(2,1)$ and I want to find C

Comment: Could the author of this question please replace $B(x_2, y_2)$ with $C(x_2, y_2)$, otherwise it doesn't make sense? I mean this part <<I want to find only using them the coordinates of $B$>>

Comment: @MaroxTn you want to find $B$

Comment: For completeness, if we ___do___ require the legs (catheti) to be parallel to the coordinate axes, there are clearly two solutions, $(x_2,y_1)$ and $(x_1,y_2)$. The latter solution is shown in the illustration.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are many solutions for $B$:

Draw a circle trough the points $A$ and $C$, with diameter $|AC|$, then all points on that circle except $A$ and $C$ are solutions

This is called [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem)

[image: illustration]

We can find the points on this circle by first finding [the equation of that circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) with center

$$O=\dfrac{A+C}{2}$$

Taking your example: $A=(4,3)$ and $C=(2,1)$ we find that

$$O=\dfrac{(4,3)+(2,1)}{2}=\dfrac{(6,4)}{2}=(3,2)$$

And the radius of the circle is $|AO|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$

So the equation of that circle is
$$(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=2$$

All points $B=(x,y)$ that satisfy this equation, except $A$ and $C$ make a right triangle with your given points.

Let's solve the equation for $y$:

$$y=\pm \sqrt{2-(x-3)^2}+2$$

So choose a value for $x$ but make sure the part under the square root will not be negative, and this will give you two valid values for $y$!

Example: choose $x=3$ then the formula gives $y=\pm \sqrt{2}+2$ so
$$B=(3,\sqrt{2}+2)$$

Is one of many solutions.

Comment: A and B are constant points, not variable points, is there any relationship between them and C ?

Comment: You mean $A$ and $C$ are constant points? these are the points that you know, and $B$ is the one you are looking for right? The drawing illustrates that all points on the circle ar possible solutions for $B$

Comment: Sorry I meant I have A and C, and I want to know B

Comment: Is it solvable ?

Comment: certainly, I solved it for you

Comment: Is every triangle with point B on this circle a right triangle though with a 90 degree angle between segments AB and BC?

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes. It's covered in the answer already: follow the link to "Thales' theorem".

Comment: +1, How did you do the gif?

Comment: @becko it's from the wikipedia page in the link

Answer (score 1):

Practically... between two push pins placed $ d= 2 \sqrt 2 $ distance apart press two sides (not hypotenuse) of a set square or triangle touching and same time rotating it. Notice that the vertex making a right angle can be *moved to many points*, in  fact around a circle of diameter $d$.