# Of the four possible outcomes from calculating a third coordinate, is there a way to narrow down to one answer from other information?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

#### EDIT

I'm going to have to rethink this. I'm not sure how to explain better, probably because my understanding is so fragile.
Thank you for your comments and I will attempt to come back later with something better.

---

new here. Please pardon any question/formatting errors or missteps. I'll make edits, if necessary.

#### Background

I'm working on a project and am trying to find the $(x,y)$ of a third point on a triangle. I've pretty much worked out how to do this, but I come up with four potential answers:
$\left(+x,+y\right)$
$\left(+x,-y\right)$
$\left(-x,+y\right)$
$\left(-x,-y\right)$

In the below image link, I've drawn an example (pardon the poor quality). In this image, I have 5 points: $P_1$ to $P_5$, where $P_4$ is off the image in the direction of the line and $P_5$ is the point I am trying to find.

[image: Imgur Image Link]

Some constants:

- This is 2 dimensional for my purposes
- The layout can fall at any angle or rotation but,

  - $P_1$ is always $(0,0)$
  - $P_5$ is always  in line with $P_3$ and $P_4$
  - $P_5$ will fall opposite of $P_3$ from $P_4$ *(using the image linked, the correct option would be $P_5d$)*

#### Question

How can I test for the "correct" one $(P_5)$ of the four answers, given that I know everything else?
I'm thinking that I should be able to take the slope of the existing points and be able to calculate the answer, but I'm at a loss on where to start.

#### Reference threads:

- [Determine the third point in right triangle only knowing the coordinates of the other two points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702990/determine-the-third-point-in-right-triangle-only-knowing-the-coordinates-of-the)
- [How to find coordinates of 3rd vertex of a right angled triangle when everything else is known?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927802/how-to-find-coordinates-of-3rd-vertex-of-a-right-angled-triangle-when-everything)
- [Calculate coordinates of 3rd point (vertex) of a scalene triangle if angles and sides are known.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187107/calculate-coordinates-of-3rd-point-vertex-of-a-scalene-triangle-if-angles-and)
- [How to find the third coordinate of a right triangle given 2 coordinates and lengths of each side](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64823/how-to-find-the-third-coordinate-of-a-right-triangle-given-2-coordinates-and-len)
- various other threads/sites, which haven't always worked out for me

#### Conclusion

Thank you in advance! I can provide specific calculations if desired, but not sure how much of what to put, since I don't think anyone wants my full calc list posted. (maybe? maybe not?)

Comment: It might help to explain the original problem that you’re trying to solve for which you get this constellation of points.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve as the explanations are incomplete (for instance, what's the role of $P_2$ ??). Anyway, it might be helpful to rotate the figure in such a way that $P_3P_4$ becomes horizontal: the problem will reduce to 1D.